# Replace column data start from number in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table i which there r 3 columns `comp_no` `comp_area` `comp_post_code`

now comp_area should have area of that place like , Toronto Vancouver, Winnipeg ...

But near about 2,290 entries r wrong and have comp_no in it like `17310 111 Ave NW`, `205 Main St` and so on. i want to remove these 2,290 entries and replace them with 0

I am using this to find these column

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `canada_database` 
WHERE comp_area !=  ''
AND comp_area NOT REGEXP  '^[[:alpha:]]'
ORDER BY slno ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

can it be done with mysql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `canada_database` 
SET comp_area =  '0'
WHERE comp_area !=  ''
AND comp_area NOT REGEXP  '^[[:alpha:]]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
UPDATE `canada_database` 
SET comp_area = 0
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id)
    FROM  `canada_database` 
    WHERE comp_area !=  ''
    AND comp_area NOT REGEXP  '^[[:alpha:]]'
)
```